# Align elements in a column to the top

Tags: flutter

How do I align the first column to the top?

I am coming from an Android Development background and normally I will just use `gravity="top"` on the container.

But how do I do it in Flutter?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Layout Test'),
          ),
          body: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[

    // The problem is here ------> 

                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.star_half),
                      Icon(Icons.star_half),
                      Icon(Icons.star_half),
                    ],
                  ),
                  _buildLongColumn(),
                  _buildLongColumn(),
                  _buildLongColumn(),
                  _buildLongColumn(),
                  _buildLongColumn(),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  Column _buildLongColumn() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        Icon(Icons.star_half),
        Icon(Icons.star_half),
        Icon(Icons.star_half),
        Icon(Icons.star_half),
        Icon(Icons.star_half),
        Icon(Icons.star_half),
        Icon(Icons.star_half),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set just `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,` in `Row`
Try out this code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Layout Test'),
          ),
          body: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[

                  // The problem is here ------>

                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.star_half),
                      Icon(Icons.star_half),
                      Icon(Icons.star_half),
                    ],
                  ),
                  _buildLongColumn(),
                  _buildLongColumn(),
                  _buildLongColumn(),
                  _buildLongColumn(),
                  _buildLongColumn(),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  Column _buildLongColumn() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        Icon(Icons.star_half),
        Icon(Icons.star_half),
        Icon(Icons.star_half),
        Icon(Icons.star_half),
        Icon(Icons.star_half),
        Icon(Icons.star_half),
        Icon(Icons.star_half),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

for more info about Rows and Column [Concept](https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-row-column-cheat-sheet-78c38d242041)

Comment: Wow so the column itself wraps its contents

Comment: Does that mean I can't control the alignment per column?

Comment: @MarkPazon if you are using column and row widgets then you have to set alignment using crossAxis and mainAxis for more info I am attaching a link in my answer 
hope it will help you to understand